# Label with wordwrap, get text that is visible on first line

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, multiline

I have a Label which only has one line and linebreakmode = wordwrap. The text of the label is bigger that will fit on the first line. What I would like is to get the text that is visible on the first line so that I can show another label with the remaining text.

So actualy I want to have a multiline label but I only want to show 1 line and I want to be able to control which of the lines is shown.

This is for a scheduler I'm making and I have to break up text into different cells.

Comment: Seems like a job for custom label renderer to me

Comment: can you explain this with code please so we can help more accuratly?

Comment: why you don't use multi-line? How did you manage to make Forms label only one line? Did you specify HeightRequest?